# Rumbling noise on sharp left turns

Tags: noise, suspension, opel, astra, cv-joint

When I do a sharp left turn (like in runabouts or hairpin turns) I hear a rumbling noise (a grumbling sound, often also like rubber rubbing against metal) from the front of my car, also I can feel a shaking.

- This only happens when doing a sharp left turn. When driving straight, long stretched left turns or right sharp turns there are no unusual sounds.
- I need to have a certain minimum velocity for the noise to happen, I think (unsure) that I need to have torque on the wheels.
- There are no suspicious noises when steering at the extreme left on a stationary vehicle.
- The sound/shaking happens during the entire left turn (provided I keep steering sharply and maintain speed), not only on the beginning/end.
- I tried to check the suspension. A first rough check did not reveal something unusual. There is no feel-able play on the joints.
- On the CV Joints there is also no feel-able play and the rubber boots are intact.

I made a [video](https://vimeo.com/228548144), the rumbling happens at 00:05. Since the roundabout is a bit larger I could not perform a very sharp turn. The noise happens only once when I was oversteering to reproduce the noise.

**Some informations about the car**

It is a 2009 Opel Astra H Caravan with about 150 KKm. It is a FWD, manual transmission.
I also have a illustration of the suspension.

[image]

I am inclined to suspect the CV Joint of the left side, perhaps somebody could point out other candidates or checks?

Comment: Have you checked the wheel bearings?

Comment: @SolarMike I tried to rock the wheels while the car was jacked up. I could not feel any play

Comment: Ok , then , as you pointed out, you need to check the cv jounts inner and outer

Comment: @SolarMike how could I do that besides to check for play?

Comment: You have to check them for play at all the possible angles that they can move through.

Comment: With wheel bearings, you really need to **hear** what they are doing. There may not be any lateral movement of the bearing at all, but you'll most likely feel/hear it if it's bad. You may want to use a automotive stethoscope to actually hear it better.

Comment: Upvote @Paulster2 , AND while the wheels are up getting listened to, safely observe the CV's during sharp left spinning, you may just see the wackiness. Safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the stabilizer bar shifted and scratched against the body behind the wheel well.

[image]