# Damaged axle spline

Tags: axle, cv-joint

Because my car made some weird [noises](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46863/rumbling-noise-on-sharp-left-turns) I decided to replace the matching CV joint. After removing it (I needed several sharp hammer blows) I discovered that the spline of the axle shaft was damaged. 
[image]

The incision in the axle is needed for a matching clip to hold the CV joint.

Is this a common fault? Was it me with removing the CV joint or was it another factor and I found the source of the noise?

Edit: The debris is just completely detached from the axle, I was able to pick it out without any effort. At them moment the axle got re-installed with the new CV-joint-

Edit 2: The photo is a bit deceptive. The tip itself is ok, the red marked half-ring is broken loose.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needs replacing... probably the source of the noise. not you though...

That type of damage is possible if a load is applied when the joint was not properly fitted and it has sheared the end : looks similar to the damage I have seen many times on broken half-shafts on axles that had been overloaded...

Comment: Do you think that the remaining spline will not be strong enough to hold the torque?

Comment: I , personally, would not refit such a damaged component - just to have it fail and have to repeat the job again...

Comment: I added some informations, perhaps there was a misconception

Comment: I didn't need the red oval you drew - I still would not refit that damaged component...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a steel making defect, nothing to do with service. I remember seeing similar pictures of internal "bursts" in cold drawn bar. I am seeing a fracture at 45 degrees to the axis making a cone-like surface. Bending fatigue would fracture at 90 degrees to the axis, torque fatigue would fracture in a spiral ; so that is why I can be certain it is not service related .

Comment: I added some informations, perhaps there was a misconception

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not a common fault. I have never seen one fail like that.

What you do not see can be the biggest problem. With that type of damage visible, there is most likely more serious damage inside the metal that will continue.

**DO NOT use this component!** You will risk continued failure of the shaft, along with loose or broken metal getting into the transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime a spline shows damage it needs to be replaced.  My question would be who curb checked that wheel?  I would think any noise would be from a nasty wobble from that wheel